# Pixel glitch poking my eyes (pstricks, beamer)

Tags: beamer, pstricks

Using pstricks and beamer I get an eye-poking pixel glitch: the pspicture "wiggles" 1 pixel or so between frames. Not sure how minimized is my example, but here it is:

Compiling with pdflatex --shell-escape
on Ubuntu, using texlive

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.28\textwidth}
\psset{xunit=1.4cm, yunit=1.4cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-1.3,-1.3)(1.3,1.3)%
\psline[linewidth=2pt](-1.25,-1.25)(1.25,1.25)%
\end{pspicture}%
\column{0.72\textwidth}%
\uncover<2>{}%
\end{columns}
\psset{xunit=0.9cm, yunit=0.9cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-4.2, -1.55)(8.1, 1.55)%
\psline(-4,-1.5)(8,1.5)%
\end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

How do I fix this? What is going on?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a problem with auto-pst-pdf. Run your example without that package and with xelatex and everything will be fine. The problem is that the included graphics which is created by `auto-pst-pdf` has its lower left outside the line whereas `xelatex` or `latex`->`dvips`->`ps2pdf` have the middle of the line as the lower left.